# How to read and processing my image files in input_fn of Estimator in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I'm new in using TF. For some reasons, I have to use TF1.10, where I found that `.ppm` is not supported by `tf.image.decode_image`.

The final goal of my network is, to read a RGBD input, and use it to generate more features (by hand-crafting methods such as sampling normals) and finally calculate loss with these additional features and ground truth.

Since my dataset is big, I used `tf.data.TextLineDataset` to get a dataset of file paths list in my `input_fn`, and tried to use `Dataset.map` to generate features. When I tried to decode the `.ppm` files I found this problem. (Code is shown below.)

OR, is there any way else to avoid transfering the path `strings` into `Tensor` before reading the images in `input_fn`, and then I can use `cv2.imread`? But if I do like this, I think I have to use all `Tensors` to build my dataset and iterator, this may cost a lot of memory. (Maybe I'm wrong.)

OR, if you think I'm completely misunderstanding the usage of `dataset` and `Estimator`, please tell me the right way. Thank you.

```
def input_fn(self, dataset, mode="train"):
    self.dict_dataset_lists = {}
    ds_rgb = os.path.expandvars(dataset["rgb"])
    ds_d = os.path.expandvars(dataset["d"])
    ds_gt = os.path.expandvars(dataset["gt"])

    self.dict_dataset_lists["rgb"] = tf.data.TextLineDataset(ds_rgb)
    self.dict_dataset_lists["d"] = tf.data.TextLineDataset(ds_d)
    self.dict_dataset_lists["gt"] = tf.data.TextLineDataset(ds_gt)

    with tf.name_scope("Dataset_API"):
        tf_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip(self.dict_dataset_lists)

        # load path to imgs(tensor)
        if mode == "train":
            tf_dataset = tf_dataset.repeat(self.parameters.max_epochs)
            if self.parameters.shuffle:
                tf_dataset = tf_dataset.shuffle(
                        buffer_size=self.parameters.steps_per_epoch * self.parameters.batch_size)
            tf_dataset = tf_dataset.map(load_img, num_parallel_calls=1) 
            tf_dataset = tf_dataset.batch(self.parameters.batch_size)
            tf_dataset = tf_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=self.parameters.prefetch_buffer_size)

    # make iterator
    iterator = tf_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    dict_tf_input = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: Can you please mention what is the problem you are facing? Unable to extract string form the tensor in `dataset.map` function? If yes, in the answer section, I have provided the soluion.